# Laravel - Import excel keep looping

Tags: php, excel, laravel

Dears,

i have an excel file with 5K rows and i'm importing it to my table in the DB successfully.

But the error, when the system finish all the rows, it keeps looping and the page doesn't stop running and not redirecting to my view.

My controller:

```php
if($request->hasFile('import_file')){
       $path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();
       $data = \Excel::load($path)->get();
       foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
       $res = policies::where('phone', '=', $row['phone'])
                      ->where('draft_no', '=', $row['draftno'])
                      ->where('due_date', '=', $duedate)
                      ->select('id')->get()->toArray();
                  if(empty($res)) {
                      $polic = new policies();
                      $polic->cust_id = $row['custno'];
                      $polic->policy = '';
                      $polic->bord_date = $borddate;
                      $polic->client_id = $row['clientid'];
                      $polic->client_no = $row['clientno'];
                      $polic->client_name = $row['clientname'];
                      $polic->draft_no = $row['draftno'];
                      if ($row['status'] == '') {
                          $polic->status = '';
                      } else {
                          $polic->status = $row['status'];
                      }

                      $polic->due_date = $duedate;
                      if ($row['curno'] == 'USD') {
                          $polic->currency = 1;
                      } else {
                          $polic->currency = 0;
                      }
                      $polic->amount = $row['amnt'];
                      $polic->zone = $row['zone'];
                      $polic->broker_id = $row['brokercode'];
                      $polic->broker_name = $row['brokername'];
                      $polic->remarks = $row['remarks'];
                      $polic->phone = $row['phone'];
                      $polic->insured_name = $row['insname'];
                      // $polic->cust_id = $row['valuedate'];
                      $polic->address = ''; //address
                      if (trim($row['status']) == 'P') {
                          $polic->paid_at = date('Y-m-d');
                      }
                      $polic->new = 1; //address
                      $polic->save();
       }
       else { 
       //am updating the imported date in the DB
       }
```

what is very strange that in my localhost is working fine, but in digitaloceans cloud, keep looping without redirecting.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I can be because you have 5000 rows to insert and 5000 insert operation consumes lots of memory. What you can try is batch insert operation.

In your policies.php make all fields fillable

protected $fillable=['cust_id ','policy','bord_date','client_id','client_no','client_name ','draft_no','bord_date','status','due_date','currency','amount','zone','broker_id','broker_name','remarks','phone','insured_name','address','paid_at','new'];

And on your excel file import use exists rather than getting collections.

```
if($request->hasFile('import_file')){
       $path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();
       $data = \Excel::load($path)->get();
$data=[];    
$i=0;  
 foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
       $res = policies::where('phone', '=', $row['phone'])
                      ->where('draft_no', '=', $row['draftno'])
                      ->where('due_date', '=', $duedate)
                      ->exists();
                  if(!$res) {
                    $i++;
                    $data[$i]['cust_id ']=$row['custno'];

                      $data['policy'] = '';
                      $data['bord_date'] = $borddate;
                      $data[$i]['client_id'] = $row['clientid'];
                      $data[$i]['client_no'] = $row['clientno'];
                      $data[$i]['client_name'] = $row['clientname'];
                      $data[$i]['draft_no'] = $row['draftno'];
                      if ($row['status'] == '') {
                          $data[$i]['status'] = '';
                      } else {
                          $data[$i]['status'] = $row['status'];
                      }

                      $data[$i]['due_date'] = $duedate;
                      if ($row['curno'] == 'USD') {
                          $data[$i]['currency'] = 1;
                      } else {
                          $data[$i]['currency'] = 0;
                      }
                      $data[$i]['amount'] = $row['amnt'];
                      $data[$i]['zone'] = $row['zone'];
                      $data[$i]['broker_id'] = $row['brokercode'];
                      $data[$i]['broker_name'] = $row['brokername'];
                      $data[$i]['remarks'] = $row['remarks'];
                      $data[$i]['phone'] = $row['phone'];
                      $data[$i]['insured_name'] = $row['insname'];
                      // $data[$i]['cust_id'] = $row['valuedate'];
                      $data[$i]['address'] = ''; //address
                      if (trim($row['status']) == 'P') {
                          $data[$i]['paid_at'] = date('Y-m-d');
                      }
                      $data[$i]['new'] = 1; //address

       }
       else { 
       //am updating the imported date in the DB
       }
}
policies::insert($data);
```

Comment: Dear,

In insertion its fine, but when i try to upload the same file, the system update the 5k rows but keeps  in loop and keeps changing